How to only show back button on navigation bar in startActivity or startActivityForResult [PAX Device]
I am using a launcher app on pax device, there's an option to open Display Settings, and after clicking that, it will navigate to android Display settings, and it's showing back button only.
here is the ui:

Here is on how I navigate to Android Wifi settings, but it's showing all navigation bar buttons, how can I display back button only?
private void wifi() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);

        activityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
    }

ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            // handle result
        });


Using Neptune SDK/PAX SDK
private IDAL iDalService = null;

//Initialize SDK
try {

            iDalService = NeptuneLiteUser.getInstance().getDal(this);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Class Name", "Error initializing Neptune SDK, message: " + e.getMessage());
        }

public void showBackButton() {

        if (iDalService != null) {
            // This will show back button only
            iDalService.getSys().enableNavigationKey(ENavigationKey.BACK, true);
        }
    }

